# XML schema - extending a pattern string

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, w3c

I'm writing an XML schema that contains a string type with a complicated pattern string.
Now I need to create a new type that uses the same pattern but with a few extra characters at the beginning.
Is there a way that I can do this without duplicating the first pattern? (which I'd rather not do because it's quite long and complicated)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen XML entities (defined in the DTD of the schema document) used for this purpose.